# Handler postDelay() new Runnables create garbage?

Tags: android, android-handler

I've been thinking about implementing `postDelay()` in my game animation to make it more smooth. What I am worried about is that `postDelay()` creates a `new Runnable` everytime it is executed. Since my game needs `postDelay()` to be executed very often, will this create a lot of garbage since it is creating a `new Runnable` every time? Or even if it does not, does the creation of a new Runnable slow down performance?

So in this case, is it appropriate to use `postDelay()` in a situation where it is going to be executed very often for a long time?

Comment: you can allocate pool of runnable and reuse them

Comment: You don't need to create a new Runnable each time. You can refer to the same with instance variable.

Comment: @Carnal But doesn't postDelay add them to a queue? I apologize if that is a stupid question, but if it is in a queue, wouldn't it have to create runnable objects anyways?

Comment: firstly, if your `postDelayed` calls create a queue, then it means that you are doing something wrong. Usually only 1 instance of your frame renderer should be in the queue at the time. Secondly, you can have the same instance into the queue at the same time, it doesn't break anything, just you don't need them there

Comment: Yes it is true,it will be added to the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single `Runnable` instance for all `postDelayed` calls.

But I think that a loop is better for games, it's a standard pattern, like in this post: [How to appear and disappear an object on screen using game loop for every five second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281888/game-loop-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create a new runnanable each time `postDely()` is executed

```
private static int LOOP_TIME = 5000;
private Handler handlerWork;

private Runnable runnableWork = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do some work
        handlerWork.postDelayed(runnableWork, LOOP_TIME);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (handlerWork == null)
        handlerWork = new Handler();
    handlerWork.postDelayed(runnableWork, LOOP_TIME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (handlerWork != null)
        handlerWork.removeCallbacks(runnableWork);
}
```